# how to reset mongodb cache

Tags: linux, mongodb

Could you please tell how to reset mongodb cache to make sure that results of query are not from cache?
Now I try to do it rebooting server:
sudo reboot.
Is there any other way?
Thank you.

Comment: This shouldn't happen by default. What driver are you using to connect? Do you have a replica set or is it standalone?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean: "This shouldn't happen by default."

Comment: I'm using php driver with mongodb, I want to make sure that data are not taked from cache or something like this, to estimate time of executing query.

Comment: I don't have replica set, it's standalone test server.

Comment: Oh, I see, you meant testing a query from disk rather than from RAM--as opposed to stale data from a cache.

Answer (score 8):

Following user366534's comment, do this:

- stop mongod
- sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
- start mongod

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB itself doesn't handle the caching. Instead, it's taken care of by the OS's virtual memory manager, as MongoDB uses Memory Mapped files. See: [Mongodb.org](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching)

I'm no Linux guru, but for dev purposes when I wanted to ensure a completely clean cache, I did a reboot as that seemed to be what made the difference.

I'm assuming you want to do this for dev/performance testing reasons rather than for production purposes too...

**Update:** 
Check out this link: http://www.linuxask.com/questions/how-to-clear-cache-from-memory-in-linux

Comment: I reboot it now to make sure results are not takes for cache to try to estimate how much time it takes to query data. Do you mean that the only way to reset cache is reboot linux?

Comment: I read this link before but I didn't understand from it, if it's necessary to reboot linux to reset cache or there is some other way.

Comment: @user366534 - If that link doesn't help, then the best thing my be to check on the mongodb forums where the 10gen guys are often lurking. I'm far from a linux expert, so this really is out of my knowledge belt :)

Comment: It's not quite clear now. I tried this command, which I don't quite understand: sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches". Maybe it worked, maybe not.  In any case than you very much for your assistance.